# Arabic speech recognition for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, speech-recognition

i'm developing a software where i need to capture specific orders by the user and determine it from a list of predefined orders.

is there anyway i can get this feature to work with support of the Arabic language?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can try pocketsphinx to accomplish this task, see:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Arabic acoustic model is available here;

http://sourceforge.net/projects/arabisc/

To learn more about CMUSphinx read the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial